# foreach loop breaks before reaching the limit

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I've been trying to list 9 tables for each student using the following code -

Up to 8 records are getting successfully printed. But for the next value of **$s**, the next student gets listed.

Where am I getting it wrong?

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `member_db` WHERE Class='$class' ORDER BY `Member_name` ASC";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$s=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($Result)) {
    foreach($row as $field) {
        if($s==10){
            $s=1; break;
        } else if($s==1){
            $sub="English (WS VOL-1)";
        } else if($s==2){
            $sub="English (WS VOL-2)";
        } else if($s==3){
            $sub="English (WS VOL-3)";
        } else if($s==4){
            $sub="Maths (WS VOL-1)";
        } else if($s==5){
            $sub="Maths (WS VOL-2)";
        } else if($s==6){
            $sub="Maths (WS VOL-3)";
        } else if($s==7){
            $sub="Science (WS VOL-1)";
        } else if($s==8){
            $sub="Science (WS VOL-2)";
        } else if($s==9){
            $sub="Science (WS VOL-3)";
        }

        echo $table;
        $s++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$table`?

Comment: it's an HTML table which I've been echoing. The code was a bit too long so I replaced that with a variable instead.

Comment: Really not sure what your code is meant to do, but you probably meant have `$s=1;` at the start of each outer loop to reset the counter.

Comment: seems you have an infinite loop. When `$s==10`, you reset `$s` to `1` and etc

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale it isn't infinite, there is a break when $s hits 10 and the while loop also ends.

Comment: You should probably look at the query result

Comment: hmm, I think the same as the loop prints the subjects fine, for e.g., Science (WS VOL-3) is getting printed but for the next student. What should be done

Comment: Perhaps `$row` must be having 8 or less elements.

Comment: so how can it be changed..?

Comment: Either use `for loop` instead of `foreach` or insert proper data into table

Answer (score 1):

try this : $i++ should be after end inner loop.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `member_db` WHERE Class='$class' ORDER BY `Member_name` ASC";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$s = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)) {
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        if ($s == 10) {
            $s = 1;
            break;
        }

        if ($s == 1) {
            $sub = "English (WS VOL-1)";
        } elseif ($s == 2) {
            $sub = "English (WS VOL-2)";
        } elseif ($s == 3) {
            $sub = "English (WS VOL-3)";
        } elseif ($s == 4) {
            $sub = "Maths (WS VOL-1)";
        } elseif ($s == 5) {
            $sub = "Maths (WS VOL-2)";
        } elseif ($s == 6) {
            $sub = "Maths (WS VOL-3)";
        } elseif ($s == 7) {
            $sub = "Science (WS VOL-1)";
        } elseif ($s == 8) {
            $sub = "Science (WS VOL-2)";
        } elseif ($s == 9) {
            $sub = "Science (WS VOL-3)";
        }
        echo $table;

    }
    $s++; //this is only change
}
```

Comment: still 8 records get printed this time only for the first subject. :(

Comment: The problem is with the while loop I think as only 8 tables per students are getting printed. Why is it so..?